# JavaScript Date instances confusion

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Let's say I create a `new Date()`, log it to the console, and see:

```
Date.toString() = Sun Sep 27 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

This tells me that the date is Sept. 27th, 2015, and my timezone is an hour ahead of UTC.

Now let's say I serialize this `Date` by calling `toISOString()` on it. The result of `toISOString()` is:

```
2015-09-26T23:00:00.000Z
```

Now let's say I send this `toISOString()` value off to a server.

Am I correct in asserting that the server receiving *only* the `2015-09-26T23:00:00.000Z` cannot know that the original `Date` on the client browser was the 27th, not the 26th?

(In other words, the timezone offset would also need to be sent to the server to know the `Date` was for the 27th.)

Comment: to ISO **STRING**. it's not an object anymore, it's a string. when that string gets sent out, the rest of the context is lost - the receiving end sees only the string, and receives NOTHING of how that string was generated, or where it came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you are correct in that, but you could guess the timezone based on the ip address.